# Get closest locations in an Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, geolocation, aggregation-framework

I have a simple document, which has 3 location objects in an array.

**Data:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c479a306b3613cf1ee5b"),
    "location_history" : [ 
        {
            "location_name" : "Area 1",
            "date" : 1472447609,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c479ac5a69612f0e0899"),
            "location" : [ 
               24.9532107, 67.1790576
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "location_name" : "Area 2",
            "date" : 1472448059,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c63bac5a69612f0e089c"),
            "location" : [ 
               24.9663937, 67.1462044
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "location_name" : "Area 3",
            "date" : 1472448987,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c9dbac5a69612f0e08a0"),
            "location" : [ 
               -24.987325, 115.1862298
            ]
        } 
}
```

**Question:** I need to fetch closest locations in this array.

**Query I have tried:**

```
db.getCollection('consumers_locations').aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$location_history"},
    {"$match":{"_id":ObjectId("57c3c479a306b3613cf1ee5b")}},
    {"$project" : { "abc" : "$location_history.location"} },
    { $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 24.942785, 67.157855 ] },
        distanceField: "distance",
        query : {"_id" : "_id"},
        uniqueDocs: true,
        includeLocs: "search_history.location",
        maxDistance : 10000
      }
    }
])
```

**But I get an error:**

> ```
> "ok" : 0,
> "errmsg" : "$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline.",
> "code" : 2,
> "codeName" : "BadValue"
> ```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c479a306b3613cf1ee5b"),
    "location_history" : [ 
        {
            "location_name" : "Area 1",
            "date" : 1472447609,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c479ac5a69612f0e0899"),
            "location" : [ 
               24.9532107, 67.1790576
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "location_name" : "Area 2",
            "date" : 1472448059,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c63bac5a69612f0e089c"),
            "location" : [ 
               24.9663937, 67.1462044
            ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not doable with your schema. Indexes are used to order documents in a collection, not sorting subdocuments within a document.

Consider to create a separate `location_history` collection with references to the parent document in  `consumers_locations`. E.g. for your object, the collection may look like:

```
db.getCollection('location_history').insert([
        {
            "consumer_location": ObjectId("57c3c479a306b3613cf1ee5b"),
            "location_name" : "Area 1",
            "date" : 1472447609,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c479ac5a69612f0e0899"),
            "location" : [ 
               24.9532107, 67.1790576
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "consumer_location": ObjectId("57c3c479a306b3613cf1ee5b"),
            "location_name" : "Area 2",
            "date" : 1472448059,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c63bac5a69612f0e089c"),
            "location" : [ 
               24.9663937, 67.1462044
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "consumer_location": ObjectId("57c3c479a306b3613cf1ee5b"),
            "location_name" : "Area 3",
            "date" : 1472448987,
            "_id" : ObjectId("57c3c9dbac5a69612f0e08a0"),
            "location" : [ 
               -24.987325, 115.1862298
            ]
        } 
]);
```

Regarding to the error, [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#behavior) read:

> You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline.

since only the first stage can benefit from indexes.

Comment: Changing of schema would be a big change, I kept it as the last thing I would do. Isn't there any other way? Something like `Stored JavaScript` or  any other thing?

Comment: But it would make data redundant @Alex Blex